# No coloration for templates in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, intellij-14, playframework-2.4

I started using the [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com) a couple weeks ago. 
Everything works quite fine, I can compile, use autocompletion in Java files and SBT is running ok,

But one thing that bugs me out is that **I have no coloration nor completion in the routes, and scala.html files.**

I thought this was normal, but this morning I saw [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/play_framework.html) where the templates are clearly completion supported.

For me, only simple HTML tags are colored. 
I checked [the requirements](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE) page, and I do have the scala plugin installed. I tried to uninstall/reinstall without success.

I use Play 2.4.4 and IntelliJ community edition 14.1.4. 
I looked for a solution on the internet, but nothing so far.

Anything I could have missed? I seems like everything should just work from the Play page and intellij websites. . . 
I have been using eclipse before, so my IntelliJ installation is pretty clean.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to recheck if play is supported by the community edition, because as far as I know it isn't.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that. Relevant comment. But none of the pages I linked seem to note that, or am I wrong? Where did you see it was a pro only feature?

Comment: Because there is a similar question a few days ago :P. This might help: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: You're right, the comparison matrix is clear. Would yo umind creating an answer so I can give you the karma points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your links about using the Play Framework with IntelliJ seem to miss the point that you need the *Ultimate Edition* of IntelliJ in order to get the full support. See the comparison Matrix where Play support (for version 1.x and 2.x) is listed as *"Supported only in Ultimate Edition"*: [IntelliJ IDEA Editions Comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

The current support, which you've noticed, is plain Java and as it seems XML, since HTML is also an "Ultimate Feature".

You may want to try the free 30-day trial of the Ultimate Edition to see if it works for you - including the Play support - and if it's worth buying it.

Comment: Just to come back on this. I downloaded and tried the ultimate version, and the support is indeed present. 200 bucks is a hefty price for pet projects though. Let's see how much better ultimate actually is :).

Comment: I personally wouldn't pay that much just to use the Play support and nothing else (like Spring). Since Eclipse is free and it can work with Play, you can also try that.